# Is this the right way to run a generic method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have this method that should set the name of objects but objects can be of 3 classes, A, B and C.

If I simply do this

```
[object setName: @"new name"];  //at this point I am treating object as of type id
```

Xcode will complain that there are multiple methods named "setName", then I am doing this

```
  if ([object isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]]) {
    [(ClassA *)object setName:newName];
  } else
  if ([object isKindOfClass:[ClassB class]]) {
    [(ClassB *)object setName:newName];
  } else
    [(ClassC *)object setName:newName];
  }
```

But this appears lame to me.

I was trying to fool Xcode by using something like this

```
    [(typeof(object))object setName:newName];
```

But Xcode is not liking it too, probably because `typeof(object)` is returning `id` and we are back to square one. Same error.

What better/elegant ways I have to do this?

Comment: What type is `object` declared to be?

Comment: Are there multiple methods named `setName` though? We need to understand why you're getting that initial error?

Comment: yes, classA, B and C all have setName

Comment: @LyndseyScott There is some other class in the application (maybe even in CoreFoundation or some other Apple library) which has a different signature for `-setName:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a protocol that class A, B, and C all conform to.

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
@required
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

And then

```
id<MyProtocol> object = ...
[object setName:newName];
```

Comment: I think that's it! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!! I will accept your answer as soon as SO let me.

Comment: I was going to suggest a protocol as well but you beat me to it. The other alternative would be to create a base class for all 3 classes that implements the setName method.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be having `A`, `B` and `C` implementing the same `protocol` that will define a method `setName`.

**NameProtocol.h**

```
@protocol NameProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

**A.h**

```
@interface A : NSObject <NameProtocol>
```

**B.h**

```
@interface B : NSObject <NameProtocol>
```

**C.h**

```
@interface C : NSObject <NameProtocol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Key-Value Coding.

```
[object setValue:newName forKey:@"name"];
```

This is a quick and dirty way, and I would recommend using a protocol, but it can be useful in the right circumstance.

---

**Update**

KVC has no compile time type checking: increasing the likelihood of defects. Runtime errors result in exceptions: defects cause the app to crash. Its syntax implies `object` is a dictionary: hiding the intent of the code. It's obscure: junior developers generally won't understand how it works and may cause maintenance issues.

It's a real horror show, but it can be useful in the right circumstance.

Comment: Can you please describe a situation when this would not be useful, which might cause problems? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig added some KVC bashing.

Comment: Thanks, now you got me curious about the _maintenance issues_ part. Could you perhaps elaborate / bash about this part a bit more? :-) Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig When using the refactoring tool to rename `name`, the string `@"name"` will not be included. When changing relationships, you might miss `name` being set this way.

Answer (score 0):

Protocols are the way to go. But you can also do:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector: @selector(setName:)])
{
    [object performSelector: @selector(setName:) withObject: name];
}
```